# FadeIn & FadeOut UISlider with UserInteraction Enabled

Tags: ios, swift, animation, alpha, uislider

I created a video duration line by using UISlider. It works nicely; and I can get slider value change. Then, I tried to add a visual (fade-in & fade-out) to it, so when user taps on the screen, the slider fades in, and fades-out if no other interaction is made.

In order to achieve fade-in & fade-out effects, I tweaked alpha between 0-1. But, ios apparently doesn't accept user-interaction for elements under alpha 0.5. Thus, I couldn't achieve that with plain `animateWithDuration`, and therefore I tried adding a counter that is counting the seconds.

(**Update:** *Clearly, what I want to achieve is that, I have a full screen video and I want to place a slider to show video time (current time + duration). I want to set the slider initially to invisible, and when user taps on the screen, the slider gets becomes visible. Then, the user makes its interaction on slider. But, I want to make the slider fade out after 5 seconds since last tap.*)

What I tried...

```
 var durationSlider: UISlider!
 var timer = NSTimer()
 var counter = 0

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    durationSlider.minimumValue = 0
    durationSlider.maximumValue = 100
    durationSlider.continuous = true
    durationSlider.alpha = 0 
    durationSlider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(durationSlider)

    let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGestureRecognizer:")
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.player.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
 }

 func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateCounting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }

 func updateCounting(){
    counter = counter + 1
 }
```

---

**Until here, everything works just fine**, and if I use only fade in without even using the counter, it works.

```
func handleTapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.durationSlider.alpha = 1.0
        print("B")

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

---

**Here start the problems**

If I try to use fade-out in completion, it directly goes inside the completion closure, so it doesn't even give me a gap of a second to interact with slider (alpha < 5).

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.4, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.durationSlider.alpha = 1.0
        print("B")

    }, completion: {completed in
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 10.0, options: [], animations: {
            print("A")
            self.durationSlider.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)

    })
```

Of course, also tried separating them into two separate functions, but this changes the print logs (so alpha) even more instantly:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.4, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.durationSlider.alpha = 1.0
        print("B")

    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 10.0, options: [], animations: {
        print("A")
        self.durationSlider.alpha = 0
    }, completion: nil)
```

---

Finally, that setting up a timer idea popped in my head so I tried something like this, **but no luck either**. It starts the counter and it's rising up but I think this logic won't work here, because it won't ever go into that if condition ever.

```
 func handleTapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    counter = 0
    scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.durationSlider.alpha = 1.0
        print("B")

    }, completion: nil)

    if counter > 6 {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 5.0, options: [], animations: {
            print("A")
            self.durationSlider.alpha = 0
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

What is the most optimal way of achieving what I want to achieve? What is the proper way of adapting fade-in & fade-out with enabling user-interaction on UISlider?

Comment: ios doesnt accept interactions when alpha value is less than 0.01.You can recieve touches for the value more than 0.02 atleast

Comment: Just under `Until here, everything works just fine` part in question, in `func handleTapGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {` I am setting the alpha to 1 and it is working as I expect. What do you mean? I want to start the alpha from 0, on tap change it to 1 and if no interaction is made for 6 seconds, disappear (alpha back to 0)

Comment: "What is the most optimal way of achieving what I want to achieve" It is unclear just _what_ you want to achieve. Instead of citing all the code that doesn't "work" (whatever that means), please describe _precisely_ what you want to have happen. "No interaction" on what? Are you saying that you want the slider to fade in and then _not_ fade out if the user _slides_ it? Do you then want the slider to fade out _after_ the user slides it? What if the user _doesn't_ slide it? And how can the user summon the slider if it is invisible? Explain _exactly_ what you want, covering all cases.

Comment: What I want to achieve is that, I have a full screen video and I want to place a slider to show video time (current time + duration). I want to set the slider initially to invisible, and when user taps on the screen, the slider gets becomes visible. Then, the user makes its interaction on slider. But, I want to make the slider fade out after 5 seconds since last tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These simple steps will do it:

1. When the user taps to show the slider, set a five-second timer (and animate the fade-in of the slider, fairly quickly, e.g. 0.3 seconds). [A nice variation might be to fade in the slider and start the timer in the animation's completion handler.]
2. On the slider's Value Changed action, invalidate / cancel the timer and create a new five-second timer. (If the user never changes the slider, this step won't happen. But that's fine; there is already a timer running.)
3. One way or another, you have a timer running, and it will eventually fire (either five seconds since you did the fade-in, or five seconds since the user last changed the slider). When the timer fires, fade out the slider. All done!

Comment: You might be helped by my CancelableTimer class: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/80551757899141e786b7f601f3879a7b450923c2/bk1ch12p499timerLeaker2/ch12p325NotificationLeaker/CancelableTimer.swift It doesn't do much that you can't do with an NSTimer, but I find it easier to manage.